# How to use HydratedBloc with Freezed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, freezed

I want to ask a question that is about a hydrated bloc with Freezed.

Firstly, I know that the we use freezed package to gain a time. We do not create all the necessary codes like creating copyWith method etc. So, If I check the generated file, I can see the toJson, fromJson methods. The problem is, I do not know should I create these methods in the state file like below code/image.

I create my state management solution with freezed, and I do not know how can I use freezed with a hydrated bloc.

To test and understand the logic, I created an app which is a counter app basically.
So, in the application folder, I have `CounterCubit` and `CounterState`.

Here my the `CounterState` file:

```
part of 'counter_cubit.dart';

@freezed
class CounterState with _$CounterState {
  const factory CounterState({
    required int number,
  }) = _CounterState;

  const CounterState._();

  factory CounterState.empty() => const CounterState(number: 0);

  factory CounterState.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CounterStateFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CounterStateToJson(this);
}
```

You can see the below image gives an error, something is wrong.

Here is the file's image:
[image: file]

The `Cubit` file working fine:
[image: file2]

In the cubit file I put also `.g` file to generate. Here I confused because I use both `freezed` package and `json_serializable` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed json_seril. package, and then wrote my own functions. I also create a sample for this, If you want to use hydrated bloc with freezed, you can find the usage of the hydrated bloc with freezed in here: https://github.com/alperefesahin/hydrated_bloc_freezed_sample